# Proof of $1 + z+z^2 +...+z^{n-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $z_{0} = 1,z_{1},...,z_{n-1} $ are the nth roots of unity, prove that:
          $$(z-z_{1})(z-z_{1})...(z-z_{n-1}) = 1 + z+z^2 +...+z^{n-1}$$

I started by letting  $p(x) = z^n -1$  which I then got $$(z-1)(z^{n-1} + z^{n-2} + ...+z+1)$$

I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the factor theorem, $z^n-1=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(z-z_i)$ (no roots can be repeated because the number of roots is equal to the degree $n$). Dropping the $z-1$ factor, $\prod_{i\ge 1}(z-z_i)=\frac{z^n-1}{z-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}z^k$ as required.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, the $n$ roots of unity are the roots of the polynomial
$$P(X)=X^n - 1$$

Therefore, for each root $z_i$, you can factorize by $X-z_i$, which gives you
$$P(X)=(X-1)(X-z_1)...(X-z_{n-1})$$

Now, just notice that $X^n-1=(X-1)(1+X+...+X^{n-1})$ to get that 
$$(X-1)(X-z_1)...(X-z_{n-1}) = 1+X+...+X^{n-1}$$

and evaluate this polynomial equality in any complex $z$ you want.