# if $1, z_1, ... , z_{n-1}$ are the solutions to $z^n = 1$, prove that $(z - z_1)(z - z_2)\dotsb(z - z_{n-1}) = 1 + z + z^2 + \dotsb + z^{n-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

I've been trying this problem but i cannot do it only with complex variable (that's the idea), it always shows up cycling polynomials and I cannot use that.

Edit: I'v been struggiling with the fact that $\frac{z^n - 1}{z-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}z^k$, and i cannot prove that

Comment: This can be found on the web everywhere, see for example [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138760/proof-of-1-zz2-zn-1), or [here](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/if-1-z1-z2-z3-zn1-are-nth-roots-of-unity-then-show-that/).


​

Comment: Hint : The given product must be equal to $\frac{z^n-1}{z-1}$. Try to find out why.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** The product $$\prod_{i=1}^n (x-r_i)$$ over the roots of a monic polynomial $p(x)$ equals $p(x)$.